# How to make following clone function accept more than one param?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm building a simple clone function:

```
function clone (value) {
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value))
}
```

The problem is that I need to do this also:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({}, object))
```

and:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({}, value, object))
```

How to modify my clone fuction to accept those additional params without breaking it?

Comment: what would you pass in as `object`? and wouldn't JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({})) result in an empty object regardless of `value` or `object` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the uses of the [`.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) method on a function is to call it with an array of arguments. You can use this to solve your problem.

```
function clone(...args) {
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify.apply(null, args))
}
```

If you need to support browsers which do not support the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator), and can't use a build tool for whatever reason, you can use `arguments` instead. But note that [`arguments` is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/arguments)

```
function clone() {
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify.apply(null, arguments))
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So your first function does the same as Sherlocked's second function?

Answer (score 1):

As we have arguments vairable inside the function that holding all the arguments that passed to that function, then we can code like this.

```
function clone (value) {
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value), arguments[1], arguments[2])
}
```

If you can use Speads syntax.

```
function clone (value) {
  var arr = arguments.slice();
  arr.shift();
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value), ...arr)
}
```

Comment: Sorry, what's `arguments` a special key?

Comment: yes, it's default local variable of function. [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)
I've update solution for case that you need more than 3 arguments

Answer (score 1):

```js
function clone () {
  var s=[];
  for (var i=0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        s.push(JSON.stringify(arguments[i]));
    }
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(s));
}
console.log(clone({a:'aa'},{b:'bb'},{c:'cc'}))
```

You can iterate through all your arguments and parse the JSON.